# How to not count duplicate null-values in rank() function in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, window-functions, ranking-functions

I'm relatively new to PostgreSQL and I'm working with window functions.

I have 2 relations: company and employee. Employee contains an information about the salary. I just wanna to get a rating of employees by their salary in ascending order.

This is my query.

```
SELECT company.name,
       e.last_name,
       e.salary,
       rank() OVER (ORDER BY e.salary nulls first )
FROM company
         LEFT JOIN employee e ON e.company_id = company.id
order by company.name;
```

So
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYy5S.png) is:

You can see that fourth and eighth rows have null-value salary. But first row with not null salary value is sixth - Kulakov got the third rank, but I need him to have the second rank.

I think it's possible not to count not null values.

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Please show us your current result *as tabular text*; also please show us the results that you expect.

Comment: Maybe you just want `DENSE_RANK()`?